# Can't see the system process list in DDMS

Tags: android, root, ddms

My phone is Nexus 4.But I still can't see the system process after it rooted.Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: Is adbd running as root?  Just adding an 'su' hack won't typically achieve that.  Although you shouldn't need root to simply view the list of processes, ddms does typically give you more detail when it talks to an adbd that is running as root.  For just listing the processes, `adb shell ps` will do the job, *without root*.

Comment: It worked,but I want to see them from DDMS, not terminal. What's more, after rooting the nexus 4, the files in data folds from [File explorer] still can't be accessed.

Comment: It would appear that your device is still "secured" rather than running as an engineering configuration (like an emulator does).  As I said before, just adding some "su" hack won't change the userid which adbd runs as.  Some of the custom ROMs do change that as well - but there are consequences of doing so you may not want to ignore.

Answer (score 0):

I just solved the problem.

Rooting the device and flashing a customized boot.img with "ro.debuggable" set to 1.

Why? Check out:
[ro.debuggable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37143960/androidstudio-what-does-debuggable-do)