# How to disable proguard optmization in Android Studio 4?

Tags: android, android-studio, proguard

Using Android Studio 4.0.1, my signed APK for release is not as good as my debug version. Looking in Internet, it looks like I need to disable proguard, but I dont know how to do it. My build.gradle file:

```
buildTypes {
    release {
        minifyEnabled false
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android-optimize.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
    }
}
```

I can’t find ‘proguard-android-optimize.txt’ in my project.

And in ‘proguard-rules.pro’, I have included:

```
-dontoptimize
-dontshrink
-dontusemixedcaseclassnames
-dontskipnonpubliclibraryclasses
-dontpreverify
-verbose
```

But I think it is not respected, and shrinking and optimization are performed, so my release apk is smaller than my debuggable apk.

How can I generate a signed APK for release without proguard touching my code?

Comment: did you try `useProguard false`?

Comment: yes, I tried, but no difference. Thanks.

Comment: With the new android studio, its actually R8 and not proguard, but it is already disabled with `minifyEnabled false`, so something else must be wrong.
So what do you mean with "not as good"? And could you provide your full build.gradle file?

Comment: Thanks; the performance of the release APK is not as good as the performance of the debuggable APK. The gradle.build file is basically the auto-generated form; I didnt include anything.

Comment: @francis duvivier Thanks again, I think "minifyEnabled false" disables proguard but enables R8? I'm not sure. I would like to disable any alteration of my code (proguard and/or R8); basically, the debuggable version works well, and the release versions I am obtaining do not work so well, because my original code is being somehow modified. Only if I include "debuggable=true" in build.gradle I get a good APK, but I think "debuggable=true" invalidates an APK to be uploaded to Google Play? Thanks for your time.

Comment: `minifyEnabled false` disables R8, and proguard is just not being used anymore, even though the rules are still named after proguard and they have taken the proguard configuration.

Comment: But pretty interesing that adding `debuggable=true` makes it better. Do you have a shareable piece of code that runs slower when it's debuggable.
Note from the below answer though that `debuggable=true` only influences the runtime behaviour and not the build.
https://stackoverflow.com/a/37148535/4962858

Comment: There are aspects of the app that have poorer performance in the release version than in the debuggable version. I've also read many people complaining about release versions crashing while debuggable versions worked flawlessly. Thanks.